# AclVoter denies access to 'LIST'

Tags: symfony, permissions, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, permission-denied

As soon as I set `sonata_admin.security.handler` to `sonata.admin.security.handler.acl` the only user who has access is the one with ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN.
I *think* I configured everything right, obviously not.

I tried:

- to give the user the real role `ROLE_VIP_CONTACT_ADMIN` instead of assigning by a fos_group, no success.
- all options for`security.access_decision_manager.strategy`: affirmative, consensus and unanimous
- to delete all acl tables, acl:init, sonata:admin:setup-acl, with and without sonata:admin:generate-object-acl and cleared the cache every time.

With no success.

```
# Acme\MyBundle\Controller\CRUDController.php

$securityContext->getAdminPermissions();
# -> ["CREATE", "LIST", "DELETE", "UNDELETE", "EXPORT", "OPERATOR", "MASTER"]

dump($this->admin->getSecurityInformation());
/* -> array:3 [▼
  "GUEST" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "VIEW"
    1 => "LIST"
  ]
  "STAFF" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "EDIT"
    1 => "LIST"
    2 => "CREATE"
  ]
  "ADMIN" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "MASTER"
    1 => "OPERATOR"
    2 => "EXPORT"
  ]
] */

dump($this->getUser()->getRoles());
/* -> array:15 [▼
  0 => "ROLE_ADMIN"
  1 => "ROLE_VIP_CONTACT_GUEST"
  2 => "ROLE_VIP_CONTACT_STAFF"
  3 => "ROLE_VIP_CONTACT_ADMIN"  # <--- I gave him everything!
  [...]
  9 => "ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH"
  [...]
  16 => "ROLE_USER"
] */
```

Now I open my browser and go to `app_dev.php/my-path-to/vip/contact/list`, resulting in an AccessDeniedException.

/edit: It's the same problem as here [ACL + SonataAdminBundle + SonataUserBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380688/acl-sonataadminbundle-sonatauserbundle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Symphony >3.1 you should use this:

```
services:
  security.acl.permission.map:
    class: Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Acl\Permission\AdminPermissionMap
```

instead

> parameters:
>       security.acl.permission.map.class: Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Acl\Permission\AdminPermissionMap

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging, the result is to let ACL know about the `LIST` permission by using Sonata's AdminPermissionMap.
See [SonataAdminBundle 5. Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/security.html) and [Documentation » Admin](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html) (Ctrl+F: security.acl.permission.map.class)

```
parameters:
    security.acl.permission.map.class: Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Acl\Permission\AdminPermissionMap
```

You might already know this.

To make a long story short: Configuration is not only done by writing some config files, but also to import the right ones.